# New to classes and my class doesn't work. Why doesn't it?

Tags: class, arraylist, processing

In my program, I want to have triangles that spin and follow your mouse position. I had it working but it was ugly because I didn't use any classes (I'm new) and just pasted the triangle over and changed the variables. This is the class I came up with.

```java
class Enemy {
  float x = random(-width, 0);
  float y = random(0, height);
  float x1;
  float x2 = -20;
  float x3 = 20;
  float y1 = (+(sqrt(3)/3)*40);
  float y2 = (-(sqrt(3)/3)*40);
  float y3 = (-(sqrt(3)/3)*40);
  float speed;
  float slope;
  float atanSlope;
  Enemy(float tempSpeed) {
    speed = tempSpeed;
  }
  void rotateEnemy() {
    float x1Rotated = rotateX(x1, y1, theta2, 0);
    y1 = rotateY(x1, y1, theta2, 0);
    x1 = x1Rotated;
    float x2Rotated = rotateX(x2, x2, theta2, 0);
    x2 = rotateY(x2, x2, theta2, 0);
    x2 = x2Rotated;
    float x3Rotated = rotateX(x3, x3, theta2, 0);
    x3 = rotateY(x3, x3, theta2, 0);
    x3 = x3Rotated;
  }
  void move() {
    slope = (y - mouseY)/(x-mouseX);
    atanSlope = atan(slope);
    if (slope < 0 && mouseY < y ) {
      x += cos(atanSlope)*(speed + speedChange);
      y += sin(atanSlope)*(speed + speedChange);
    } else if (slope >= 0 && mouseY < y) {
      x -= cos(atanSlope)*(speed + speedChange);
      y -= sin(atanSlope)*(speed + speedChange);
    } else if (slope > 0) {
      x += cos(atanSlope)*(speed + speedChange);
      y += sin(atanSlope)*(speed + speedChange);
    } else {
      x -= cos(atanSlope)*(speed + speedChange);
      y -= sin(atanSlope)*(speed + speedChange);
    }
  }
  void drawEnemy() {
    translate(x, y);
    triangle(x1, y1, x2, x2, x3, x3);
    translate(-x, -y);
  }
  void collisionDetect() {
    if (abs(mouseX-x) + abs(mouseY-y)  < 80)
      if (isDeadly) {
        respawn();
        energy -= height/16;
        points += 500;
      } else
        energy = 0;
  }
  void respawn() {
    int ranQuadrant1 = (int)random(0, 2);
    int ranSide1 = (int)random(0, 2);
    if (ranQuadrant1 == 0) 
      if (ranSide1 == 0) 
        x = random(0, -width/2);
      else {
        x = random(width, 3*width/2);
        y = random(-height/2, 3*height/2);
      } else 
    if (ranSide1 == 0) 
      y = random(0, -height/2);
    else {
      y = random(height, 3*height/2);
      x = random(-width/2, 3*width/2);
    }
  }
}
```

And I use it like this

```java
ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
void setup() {
  for (i = 0; i<difficulty; i++); 
    enemies.add(new Enemy(i*5));

  for (i = 0; i<enemies.size()-1; i++)
      enemies.get(i).respawn();
}
void draw() {
 for(i = enemies.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    enemies.get(i).rotateEnemy();
    enemies.get(i).move();
    enemies.get(i).drawEnemy();
    enemies.get(i).collisionDetect();
}
```

When I run it, the triangles don't draw. Not only that, some ellipses I wrote that come right after trying to draw the triangles don't draw either. The square that follows your mouse along with a timer and other things DO draw though. Please help. Thank you!
Now, this isn't the whole program. I'm making a game for a project and these triangles are the enemies.
If you want to see the whole program for context/if I didn't put enough, I put it in a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/Bfd4Fk6t

Comment: Even in your pastebin you don't show the crucial parts of your program: Show us the code of the `translate` and `triangle` methods

Comment: Oops I forgot how different processing is from java. I wrote this in processing. It's kind of like a java library. I removed the java tag sorry.

Comment: Okay I realized I forgot to initialize the x and y variables. It draws... something. It definitely isn't the triangle I want though.

Comment: In the future please try to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, turns out I'm a dummy.
Look at the rotateEnemy function for the 2nd and 3rd points. There are no y's only x's. I was using a lot of find and replace when copying it over so I must have gotten rid of the y's and replaced them with x's. Another error is in drawEnemy, I draw the triangle with parameters (x1,y1,x2,x2,x3,x3). No y's again. Geez I'm a smart guy lol.